# How to pass arguments to scoring file when deploying a Model in AzureML

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am deploying a trained model to an ACI endpoint on Azure Machine Learning, using the Python SDK.
I have created my score.py file, but I would like that file to be called with an argument being passed (just like with a training file) that I can interpret using `argparse`.
However, I don't seem to find how I can pass arguments
This is the code I have to create the InferenceConfig environment and which obviously does not work.  Should I fall back on using the extra Docker file steps or so?

```py
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

env = Environment('my_hosted_environment')
env.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(
    conda_packages=['scikit-learn'],
    pip_packages=['azureml-defaults'])
scoring_script = 'score.py --model_name ' + model_name
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script=scoring_script, environment=env)
```

Adding the score.py for reference on how I'd love to use the arguments in that script:

```py
#removed imports
import argparse

def init():
    global model

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Load sklearn model")
    parser.add_argument('--model_name', dest="model_name", required=True)
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name=args.model_name)
    model = joblib.load(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    try:
        data = json.loads(raw_data)['data']
        data = np.array(data)
        result = model.predict(data)
        return result.tolist()

    except Exception as e:
        result = str(e)
        return result
```

Interested to hear your thoughts

Comment: Can you please add more details about the use case/score.py and error logs that you are getting.

Comment: thanks, I added the score.py

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How to deploy using environments can be found here [model-register-and-deploy.ipynb](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAzure%2FMachineLearningNotebooks%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fhow-to-use-azureml%2Fdeployment%2Fdeploy-to-cloud%2Fmodel-register-and-deploy.ipynb&data=02%7C01%7CRamprasad.Mula%40microsoft.com%7Ce06d310b0447416ab46b08d7bc836a81%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637185146436156499&sdata=uQo332dpjuiNqWFCguvs3Kgg7UUMN8MBEzLxTPyH4MM%3D&reserved=0) .  InferenceConfig class accepts  source_directory and entry_script [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py#parameters), where source_directory  is a path to the folder that contains all files(score.py and any other additional files) to create the image.

This [multi-model-register-and-deploy.ipynb](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/deployment/deploy-multi-model/multi-model-register-and-deploy.ipynb) has code snippets on how to create InferenceConfig with source_directory and entry_script.

```
from azureml.core.webservice import Webservice
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.environment import Environment

myenv = Environment.from_conda_specification(name="myenv", file_path="myenv.yml")
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="score.py", environment=myenv)

service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                       name='sklearn-mnist-svc',
                       models=[model], 
                       inference_config=inference_config,
                       deployment_config=aciconfig)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)

print(service.scoring_uri)
```

Comment: Hello Ram, thanks a lot for the feedback.  However, I seem to miss where the actual arguments get passed into the score.py script?  They just seem to call the script, without any specific parameters and the model name is 'hardcoded' in the script, as far as I see it?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run#passing-arguments-from-pipeline-submission-to-script

Comment: Can you try using our new easier way to accomplish this using parallelrunstep? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-parallel-run-step

Comment: This answer does not provide any solution for the raised question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a year old. Providing a solution to help those who may still be looking for an answer. My answer to a similar question is [here](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F67689671%2Fhow-to-get-reference-to-azureml-workspace-class-in-scoring-script%2F68486018%2368486018&data=04%7C01%7Cprba%40microsoft.com%7C71c3f6cd71f448ad7d1b08d94d198bdb%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637625594389498821%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=UnFCnUlJ72Kl6amGmmAuHltSunSRfzK4%2BDFWFI495NQ%3D&reserved=0). You may pass native python datatype variables into the inference config and access them as environment variables within the scoring script.

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this problem differently. I could not find a (proper and easy to follow) way to pass arguments for *score.py*, when it is consumed by *InferenceConfig* . Instead, what I did was following 4 steps:

1. Created score_template.py and define variables which should be assigned
2. Read content of score_template.py and modify it by replacing variables with desired values
3. Write modified contents into score.py
4. Finally pass *score.py* to *InferenceConfig*

STEP 1 in score_template.py:

```
import json
from azureml.core.model import Model
import os
import joblib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def init():
    global model
    #model = joblib.load('recommender.pkl')
    model_name="#MODEL_NAME#"
    model_saved_file='#MODEL_SAVED_FILE#'
    try: 
        model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), model_saved_file)
        model = joblib.load(model_path)
    except:
        model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name)
        model = joblib.load(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    try:
        #data=pd.json_normalize(data) 
        #data=np.array(data['data'])
        data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]
        data = np.array(data)
        result = model.predict(data)
        # you can return any datatype as long as it is JSON-serializable
        return {"result": result.tolist()}
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        #error= data
        return error
```

STEP 2-4 in deploy_model.py:

```
#--Modify Entry Script/Pass Model Name--
entry_script="score.py"
entry_script_temp="score_template.py"

# Read in the entry script template
print("Prepare Entry Script")
with open(entry_script_temp, 'r') as file :
  entry_script_contents = file.read()

# Replace the target string
entry_script_contents = entry_script_contents.replace('#MODEL_NAME#', model_name)
entry_script_contents = entry_script_contents.replace('#MODEL_SAVED_FILE#', model_file_name)
# Write the file to entry script
with open(entry_script, 'w') as file:
  file.write(entry_script_contents)

#--Define configs for the deployment---
print("Get Environtment")
env = Environment.get(workspace=ws, name=env_name)
env.inferencing_stack_version = "latest"
print("Inference Configuration")
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script=entry_script, environment=env, source_directory=base_path)
aci_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = int(cpu_cores), memory_gb = int(memory_gb),location=location)

#--Deloy the service---
print("Deploy Model")
print("model version:", model_artifact.version)
service = Model.deploy( workspace=ws,
                        name=service_name,
                        models=[model_artifact],
                        inference_config=inference_config,
                        deployment_config=aci_config,
                        overwrite=True )

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```